# Python dictionary key value comparison

Tags: python

I have data that comes through in this format:

```
reg_data1 = {
    'request_id': 'bc94f069-ea3c-4465-8112-3a236b6ed8ea', 
    'profile_name': '2.0b', 
    'transport_name': 'simpleHttp', 
    'transport_address': 'None', 
    'report_only': False, 
    'xml_signature': False, 
    'ven_name': 'dan_test', 
    'http_pull_model': True
}

reg_data2 = {
    'request_id': 'bc94f069-ea3c-4465-8112-3a236b6ed8ea', 
    'profile_name': '2.0b', 
    'transport_name': 'simpleHttp', 
    'transport_address': 'None', 
    'report_only': False, 
    'xml_signature': False, 
    'ven_name': 'dan_test_asdf', 
    'http_pull_model': True
}
```

I am trying to create a function `find_ven` to see if the `ven_name` exists in `VENS` if it does exist return the `ven_id` and `regresistration_id` else return `False`

```
# Future db
VENS = {
    "1": {"ven_name": "dan_test", "ven_id": "ven_id_dan_test", "registration_id": "reg_id_dan_test"},
    "2": {"ven_name": "slipstream_ven1", "ven_id": "ven_id_slipstream_ven1", "registration_id": "reg_id_slipstream_ven1"},
    "3": {"ven_name": "volttron_test", "ven_id": "ven_id_volttron_test", "registration_id": "reg_id_volttron_test"}     
}



def find_ven(data):
    print("TRYING TO LOOK UP VEN ",data['ven_name'])
    for values in VENS.values():
        #print(values['ven_name'])
        if (values['ven_name']) in data['ven_name']:
            print(f"found {values['ven_name']} in payload, looking to match {data['ven_name']}")
            #return v['ven_id'],v['registration_id']
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Can someone give me a tip where I am going wrong as both `reg_data1` and `reg_data2` both return `True` but `reg_data2` should return `False` as the `reg_data2` `ven_name` doesnt exist in `VENS`. Ultimately I am trying to use the `find_ven` function to return `ven_id` & `registration_id` else `False`

Both return `True`:

```
find_ven(reg_data1)
find_ven(reg_data2)
```

Any tips appreciated thanks

Comment: `if (values['ven_name']) in data['ven_name']:` is the problem, it checks whether `'dan_test'` is a substring of `'dan_test_asdf'`, which is true. Replace it with `if values['ven_name'] == data['ven_name']:` and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made your code easier to read, your issue was using `in` instead of `==`:

```
def find_ven(data):
    print("TRYING TO LOOK UP VEN ",data['ven_name'])
    ven_name = data['ven_name']
    for v in VENS.values():
        #print(values['ven_name'])
        if v.get('ven_name') == ven_name:
            print(f"found {v.get('ven_name')} in payload, looking to match {ven_name}")
            #return v['ven_id'],v['registration_id']
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Thanks Ill hit the green check when I can

Answer (score 1):

What others stated is true, the problem was using `in`. But also you should consider moving the `return false` statement outside the for loop or it will never iterate through all the `VENS` entries.

```
def find_ven(data):
     print("TRYING TO LOOK UP VEN ",data['ven_name'])
     for values in VENS.values():
         #print(values['ven_name'])
         if (values['ven_name']) == data['ven_name']:
             print(f"found {values['ven_name']} in payload, looking to match {data['ven_name']}")
             #return v['ven_id'],v['registration_id']
             return True
     return False
```